Having some problem with this int.parse using IronXL
I am using ironxl to import Excel data into a C# dictionary and I am unable to run the script:
public Dictionary<string, int> ReadInputData_3()
{


    // Check if the file exists

    Dictionary<string, int> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    WorkBook workBook =   WorkBook.Load("..\\..\\..\\ModbusTestJig.Helpers\\Input_data\\Input_data.xlsx");
    //WorkSheet workSheet = workBook.WorkSheets.First();
    WorkSheet workSheet = workBook.WorkSheets[0];
    foreach (var row in workSheet.Rows)
    {
        var key = row.Columns[0].Value.ToString(); // Assuming key is in the first column (column index 0)
        var value = row.Columns[1].Value.ToString(); // Assuming value is in the second column (column index 1)

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            dataDictionary.Add(key,int.Parse(value));
            //dataDictionary[key] = value;
        }
    }


    return dataDictionary;


}


Please tell us what goes wrong - for example, if there is an error message then we need to know what the error message is; if the output is not as expected, then we need to know the input, the output you get, and the output you want.

You should tag your question with ironxl. I don't have a clue why you've tagged it mstest

@Flydog57 It looks like you have enough reputation to edit the tags.

I do, but it's really the responsibility of the poster to do that. Editing your question in response to comments is something folks new to SO should learn. @Coderstnam: the importance of getting the tags right cannot be dismissed. There may be some expert on `ironxl' who dutifully monitors that tag, and who may know the answer to your question without thinking

...I was bored
public static Dictionary<string,Int32>? ReadInputData_3()
{
    const String XLSX_RELATIVE_PATH = @"..\..\..\ModbusTestJig.Helpers\Input_data\Input_data.xlsx";

    FileInfo xlsxFile = new FileInfo( XLSX_RELATIVE_PATH );
    if( !xlsxFile.Exists )
    {
        _ = MessageBox.Show( "Couldn't find file \"" + xlsxFile.FullName + "\".", MessageBoxIcon.Error, etc );
        return null;
    }

    WorkBook workBook = WorkBook.Load();
    if( workBook.WorkSheets.Count < 1 )
    {
         _ = MessageBox.Show( "Workbook doesn't contain any worksheets.", MessageBoxIcon.Error, etc );
        return null;
    }

    Dictionary<String,Int32> dict = new Dictionary<String,Int32>( StringComparer.Ordinal );

    WorkSheet workSheet = workBook.WorkSheets[0];

    foreach( RangeRowrow in workSheet.Rows )
    {
        Object? col0Value = row.Columns[0].Value; // Assuming key is in the first column (column index 0)
        Object? col1Value = row.Columns[1].Value; // Assuming value is in the second column (column index 1)

        String key      = col0Value?.ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ).Trim() ?? String.Empty;
        String valueStr = col1Value?.ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ).Trim() ?? String.Empty;

        if( !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( key ) && Int32.TryParse( valueStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, NumberStyles.Any, out Int32 i32 )
        {
            if( !dict.TryAdd( key, i32 ) )
            {
                _ = MessageBox.Show( "Encountered duplicate key \"" + key + "\"", MessageBoxIcon.Error, etc );
            }
        }
    }

    return dict;
}



I am new to C# and automation sir. thanks for the help!
